# Why have 3 external HDDs failed after a few hours of use?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have purchased 3 HDDs in the past month and every time after copying about 1.5TB of data on to them they fail. The first 2 HDDs were Samsung 4TB drives and the third one is a Seagate Expansion 4TB.

- The model number of the most recent drive (Seagate) is: STEA4000400
- The first 2 drives (Samsung) were: HX-M401TCB/G
- My computer is a Thinkpad Yoga 12
- All drives are powered by the USB port; no external power supply.

What I do is buy the HDD I need then plug it into my computer (running Linux) and transfer the data (about 2TB) from my old HDD (also a 4TB portable Samsung drive). After a few hours of copying the transfer speed slows down alot and then the drive fails and won't mount on either my machine or any other machine, and it makes a very faint ticking sound when connected. I have tried reformatting the drives (sometimes I am able to mount the drive long enough to reformat) but it does not help.

Comment: Define "Failed" and exactly how you know they have failed? What do the SMART stats for the disk say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suspect, that those drives haven't failed at all - they were just running out of their specs and should be fine when plugged into a different computer.

Let me explain:

You use the USB ports of your Yoga for two purpouses:

- As a data connection, all fine with that
- As a power source for the drives, and that might be the problem.

Now the Yogas are notorious for providing less-than-promised current on their USB ports - this results in the disks being always close to starving for power, as writing to a 4TB drive typically comes quite close to the design limits of power draw.

You could use a (quality!) powered USB hub to overcome this - in such a pattern the juice for the drive would be provided by the hub's power supply, not the Yoga.

Comment: dont know if this is the case, but its worth checking.

Comment: I am thinking that this may be the case now since my 3rd HDD seems to be working again. However I am not certain yet because I remember trying the first HDD on another computer before returning it and it didn't work. Is it possible that my computer somehow damaged the drive by not providing enough power?

Comment: I consider it unlikely, that it would be physically damaged, but the partition table and file system might have been trashed beyond repair, needing a clean restart.